# Question about: If I do

Tags: will-would

Should I use ***present|past*** tense in the following sentence and why?

Question:

> How are you going to travel?

Reply:

> We are going by train. If we ***go***|**went** by bus, it would be cheaper, but the
>   train is quicker.

Comment: You can use either. No one has complained (yet) about the Lennon/McCartney song that begins with "If I fell in love with you, would you promise to be true and help me understand..."

Answer (score 1):

Simple past is correct in this if-clause.

You use the simple present if the decision/action/whatever takes place in the future: `If we go by bus, it will be cheaper`

In case of already decided matters that are impossible or unlikely to happen you typically use the simple past: `If we went by bus, it would be cheaper`

For probable things you use the present perfect: `If we have gone by bus, we will have saved money.`

Comment: Since the question is "How are you *going* to travel", it's not unusual to match the verb by answering, "If we *go* by bus ..." Also, in this case "If we went" is short for, "if we were to go", which indicates hypothetical action but, in my opinion, says nothing about probability.